# Preparing a Callback URL for Indodax API using PHP

Tags: php, api, curl

I am trying to make a php script to communicate with the indodax API endpoint. from the documentation provided there are some line that make me confused, namely in the following sentence: ( [https://github.com/btcid/indodax-official-api-docs/blob/master/Private-RestAPI.md#withdraw-coin-endpoints](https://github.com/btcid/indodax-official-api-docs/blob/master/example/Private-RestAPI-php.md#withdraw-coin) )

*"You also need to prepare a Callback URL. Callback URL is a URL that our system will call to verify your withdrawal requests. Various parameters will be sent to Callback URL, make sure to check this information on your server side. If all the data is correct, print out a string “ok” (without quotes). We will continue the request if only we receive “ok” (without quotes) response, otherwise the request will be failed."*

Questions:

1. If I write a php script at https://www.ok.com/withdraw.php , then the URLCallback is https://www.ok.com/withdraw.php ? true or false ?
2. from the API document above :
   "If all the data is correct, print out a string “ok” (without quotes). We will continue the request if only we receive “ok” (without quotes) response, otherwise the request will be failed."
   what is "ok" (without quotes) response? does it have to be written in php script or not? if yes, please help me complete this code.

```html
    <?php
    $url = 'https://indodax.com/tapi';
    // Please find Key from trade API Indodax exchange
    $key = '****';
    // Please find Secret Key from trade API Indodax exchange
    $secretKey = '****';
    
    $data = [
        'method' => 'withdrawCoin',
        'timestamp' => '1578304294000',
        'recvWindow' => '1578303937000',
        'currency' => 'doge',
        'withdraw_address' => 'D9iCdBLBosJzGSvpQGMSobwtdgB2rS1zam',
        'withdraw_amount' => '10',
        'withdraw_memo' => 'memo',
        'request_id' => 'trx002'
    ];
    $post_data = http_build_query($data, '', '&');
    $sign = hash_hmac('sha512', $post_data, $secretKey);

    $headers = ['Key:'.$key,'Sign:'.$sign];

    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);
    echo $response;
```

I've tried to make a php script as above with the api key and secret key ( https://github.com/btcid/indodax-official-api-docs/blob/master/example/Private-RestAPI-php.md#withdraw-coin )  . then the result is

"{"success":0,"error":"did not pass callback check","request_error":"","callback_response":"error code: 1020"}
"

Comment: _"what is "ok" (without quotes) response?"_ - just the literal text `ok`. Your script has to respond with only that as output in this case, and nothing else.

Comment: according to the documentation, ok response should be received by indodax API endpoint

"We will continue the request if only we receive “ok” (without quotes) response"

Comment: Yes, and? They request your script from their end, and you respond (after checking the data they sent you) with a simple `ok`. Where is the confusion about something this simple?

Comment: i just started writing code just by copy pasting the example and editing a few lines.
so writing a few simple lines of code looks like a problem to me.
can you complete the script above including sending an "ok" response to the api endpoint.

Comment: The script you have there isn't for the callback URL in the first place - that is the API request you make to trigger a withdrawal from _your_ end.

Comment: can you provide an example script as you mentioned earlier? 
"The script for the callback URL in the first place"

Comment: Your script gets passed parameters via POST, same as a form submission would. You need to validate that data in whatever form you deem necessary, and then respond with nothing but the text `ok`.